# Is it possible to do 2d character movement with vectors instead of using tiles

Tags: java, 2d, character

we have a character moving through a house and so far we used tiles to simulate character movement. Is it possible to use a vector image of the character and move the points via vectors to simulate movement.

We programm in java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "tiles" do you mean frames? As in the character is using frame-based animations? And when you say "move the points via vectors" do you mean having a vector image and simply moving it's points around to animate them?

Comment: exactly, that is what i mean.

Comment: What would make this impossible? What specific obstacle have you come up against when you've tried implementing it so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animating vector images is definitely possible, and it's how flash used to work with. How to do that? Well, you haven't revealed a lot of details about how you work, so it's hard to give the best option, so here are two of them I can think of:

- **Using animation software**: There are programs with which you can animate images and export them for use, one I've heard of is [DragonBones](https://dragonbones.github.io/en/index.html). Ideally you'd have your graphics designer to work with it, and export the characters in such a format to use in your game. Unfortunately I'm not sure how that can be done with Java.
- **Programmatically**: If for whatever reason, this is a project to learn, you can also design a small animation engine yourself. This can be very simple like "Object moves from A to B", to something more complicated like supporting rotation, scale and more.

It's difficult to go into more details without going off-topic, however this should answer your question: **Yes**, it **is** possible to do vector-based animations.

In a way, all 3D graphics are essentially vector-based, which can prove that potentially you can do a lot of things with vector-based animations.

Comment: I had this idea because i know its vector-based in 3D-games. The obstacle is, that the company (kind of a hospital) created a little game for their patients without knowing how games nowadays work. Everything is written in java, their are a bunch of design flaws, no engine and they want to move towards version 1.0. They have performance issues, running on office-computers and a bunch of bugs.

Comment: I do an internship there as a programmer.

Comment: @Zehke I'm afraid there's not much users here can do to help. The easiest option would be to use 2D animation software, but then you have to do research of how to export it properly in a format that java will understand.